# BlueTooth connections on iOS - App Crashes when connection established

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, gamekit

I'm programming a metronome app that establishes a Bluetooth connection through GameKit and the PeerPickerController and then allows one device to send the controls through to the other, so if start is pressed on one device, the metronome starts on both.

The App loads fine and searches for other devices and says that its connected in the debugger window of Xcode, but then crashes immediately with this error:

> wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
>
> 2012-05-27 20:51:50.820 MetroConnect[5689:707] -[MetroConnectViewController session:didFailWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1793f0
>   2012-05-27 20:51:50.824 MetroConnect[5689:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MetroConnectViewController session:didFailWithError:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1793f0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x3126388f 0x375a1259 0x31266a9b 0x31265a83 0x311c0650 0x34141b5f 0x311c21fb 0x31b7f747 0x31237ad3 0x3123729f 0x31236045 0x311b94a5 0x311b936d 0x33233439 0x3091ccd5 0x5023 0x4fc8)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

I was wondering if anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong? I have made a different App in a similar way that sends chat messages between two devices and that works fine and I can't see any differences between this implementation and the Metronome implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you are the GKSession delegate, yet don't implement the required delegate methods.  They are required for a reason, after all.  Implement the session:didFailWithError: method with something like this and check that you have the rest of them implemented properly:

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Session connection failed with error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Ok so I implemented the above code and then got this error:

Session connection failed with error Invalid parameter for -setDataReceiveHandler:withContext:

I found the line of code that this referred to in the peerPickerController method. Here it is with the method name:

` -(void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID to Session:(GKSession *)session`

`[session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];`


Any idea what this error could mean? Thank you so much for your help. @CodaFi